# DataGrid with RowDetailsTemplateSelector: display secondary DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

we have a problem with WPF and how to access data in a DataTemplate driven by use of RowDetailsTemplateSelector of main DataGrid. Main DataGrid displays Customer items, and each Customer has a list of Contact items. When selecting a Customer, we want the data template to display a list of the Contact items it contains. Thank you for any good resource/help.

Here is the gist of what we've come up so far :

https://gist.github.com/postb99/5900055

Comment: You want access to the `DataTemplate` behind code through `RowDetailsTemplateSelector`?

Comment: We finally found out the correct binding.